# 'mapper_parsing_exception' illegal field [ignored_above], only fields can be specified inside fields' error in elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search and i am trying to create a mapping file for an index
this is my mapping file for creating an index

```
{
"mapping": {
    "properties": {
        "TotalCapacity": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        "DiskUseState": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignored_above": 256
            }
        },
        "DriveHostName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignored_above": 256
            }
        },
        "ModelNumber": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignored_above": 256
            }
        },
        "DriveNodeUuid": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignored_above": 256
            }
        },
        "DrivePath": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignored_above": 256
            }
        },
        "DriveProtocol": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignored_above": 256
            }
        }  
    }
    
}
```

}

when i try to create an index  iam getting this error

```
'mapper_parsing_exception' illegal field [ignored_above], only fields can be specified inside fields' error in elastic search.
```

Not sure whats wrong . Any help is appriciated
Elasticsearch version : 7.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issue with your mapping configuration:

First, it should `ignore_above` and not `ignored_above`.

Second, You have not given sub field name. your field mapping should be something like below, so you can access `keyword` type of field using `DiskUseState.keyword` name:

```json
"DiskUseState": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {           <---- this you have not given in your mapping
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
```

**Correct field mapping**

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "TotalCapacity": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "DiskUseState": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "DriveHostName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "ModelNumber": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "DriveNodeUuid": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "DrivePath": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "DriveProtocol": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```